# basic HTML help. Not able to split page into three

Tags: html, css

i am trying to split the web page to three equal sections but even when i put width as 33% for all three divs, the third div will go to new line.If i make the last div as 32% it will come back in line.
 there is no margin or padding for the divs or even for the container.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Please show us the HTML in question.

Comment: Would you mind accepting an answer? :)

Answer (score 6):

Here's a *very* quick solution to your issue.

```css
body {
    padding: 0;
}

.col-container {
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

.col-third {
    width: 33%;
    float: left;
}

.col-third:first-child, .col-third:last-child {
    background: wheat;
}

.col-third:nth-child(2n){
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-container">
    <div class="col-third">
        <p>content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-third">
        <p>content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-third">
        <p>content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Click run snippet to see

Answer (score 0):

Having access to your code would make it easier to answer to your questions, as @davejagoda had said.

But what I would recommend is that you use [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) to make things easier for you. With Bootstrap, you could use a class of `col-md-4` for each section within a `row` div, like:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">...</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">...</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">...</div>
</div>
```

Then you add a custom `zero` class (you can call it whatever you like), as in:

```
<div class="zero row">
  <div class="zero col-md-4">...</div>
  <div class="zero col-md-4">...</div>
  <div class="zero col-md-4">...</div>
</div>
```

And finally you customize padding and margin to the additional `.zero` class, like:

```
.zero {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

That should do the job.

I hope to have helped. If I have, please mark this answer as useful. If you need more assistance, feel free to [contact](http://virtuacreative.github.io/git/contact.html) me.

Sorry, I forgot something:

In order to make it work, just add this link to the `<head>...</head>` of your document:
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">`

It contains all Bootstrap CSS last updated library. You can also grab the javascript file if you want to play around with extra animated options.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it should work:

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
body {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  text-align: center;
}
.div1 {
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
.div2 {
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
.div3 {
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="div1">
    Hola
  </div>
  <div class="div2">
    Hola
  </div>
  <div class="div3">
    Hola
  </div>
</body>
```